# How order text extracted from pdf?

Tags: parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing

I'm building a pdf parser that extract text and save it into a txt file.
I'm doing that by tracing all content objects, then decode the streams using the font encoding.
what I found I bit challenging is how to place the text in its right order, I don't care about how really it looks, all I want is the order of the sequences, I don't care about font size,space between text...etc.

So how can I deal with Tm,Td,TD and T* if all I care about is the order?

Another question sometimes one content object contains streams that are from 2 different pages how can I know when the streams of the next page started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As your question is very generic, this answer also is generic.*

> So how can I deal with Tm,Td,TD and T* if all I care about is the order?

There are a few main options only:

- You may ignore everything except the text showing operators, in particular you ignore the mentioned operators. A relevant number of documents allow pretty faithful text extraction that way as the text showing operators in those documents occur in the natural reading order.

  *Considering that you ask this question at all, though, seems to indicate that you have encountered documents that are differently built.*
- If the documents in question are appropriately tagged, you can use the **MCID**s in the content stream in combination with the document structure tree to sort (and categorize!) the text pieces you extract as before. For tagged documents this usually results in a reasonable good text extraction result.
- Otherwise, even if you "only" care about the order, you have to extract the exact positions of the text pieces together with those pieces themselves and eventually sort them accordingly. And this means not only considering the operations you mention but also **cm** (changes the current transformation matrix), **q** (saving the current graphics state), and **Q** (restoring the current graphics state).

  Furthermore, for a solution for a very wide range of documents you also have to analyze the layout to recognize multiple columns and text belonging to figures instead of the main text flow.

Of course there may be some variations of those main options, for example assuming the order of text objects to be correct and only sorting inside them; those may allow to ignore some operators, e.g. in the example just mentioned one may ignore **cm**, **q**, and **Q** as they are not allowed in text objects.

> Another question sometimes one content object contains streams that are from 2 different pages how can I know when the streams of the next page started?

I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Do you mean that the same content stream is referenced from multiple page objects which show only certain, probably distinct parts of the content? In that case you have to extract the exact position of the text pieces, too, and check whether they are inside or outside the crop box of the respective page.

**EDIT**

*In comments you meanwhile clarified and supplied example data. Analyzing that data gives rise to the following addition:*

First of all, not everything you marked blue in the content stream of page 16 can be found on page 17 instead of page 16; for example very early (in the second line of your "closer look at object 127") you can see the instruction drawing the page number, `(16)Tj`, which is to be found on page 16, not 17.

But indeed, soon a large section of text objects starts for which you find the text in a viewer only on page 17, not 16. The reason for this is that those text objects draw outside the visible page area and outside the current clip path!

In more detail:

Both page 16 and 17 have a **CropBox** of `[ 0.0 0.0 481.89 680.315 ]`, i.e. the visible area is the part of the canvas with (0, 0) in the bottom left corner and (481.89, 680.315) in the top right one.

Then you find the following instructions early in the part of the page 16 content you marked in blue:

```cos
0 0 481.89 680.315 re
W n
```

This intersects the current clip path with the rectangle with (0, 0) in the bottom left corner and (481.89, 680.315) in the top right one.

Thus, everything drawn outside that box on page 16 is invisible for two reasons.

But the following text objects in that content marked in blue draw text at positions with negative **x** coordinates! For example immediately after the clip path changing instructions above:

```cos
BT
0 0 0 1 k
/GS1 gs
/C2_0 1 Tf
15 0 0 15 -441.875 556.9449 Tm
[<0003007000640059006E005F004300D0>-48<00030044004C>-47<000300CA006E>1<0066003D00ED>-48<000300BA007B0065005C003D>-48<000300700059006E005F005500D0>-47<0003007000650063009D004300D0>-48<0003007F006800FD00DA>-48<00030007000C000C000C0008>-45<0003006E006900CC>-47<000300EF007B00640052>-49<000300BA007B005F003D00ED>-48<000300EC007B004100ED>-48<00030101>-47<0003007B0065002200D0>]TJ
ET
EMC 
/Span <</MCID 243 >>BDC 
BT
/C2_0 1 Tf
15 0 0 15 -441.875 534.9449 Tm
[<0003008B0053007D003D>-289<0003007000650063009D0043006E003D>-289<000300D2007B00680062004300D0>-291<000300E50077>]TJ
ET
EMC
```

The fifth entries of those text matrix setting instructions (**Tm**) essentially is the **x** coordinate from which the following text drawing instruction will draw text left-to-right. The value of `-441.875` there clearly is outside the box mentioned above.

If you look at the content stream of the following page 17, you'll find similar instructions for drawing the same text:

```cos
BT
/C2_0 1 Tf
15 0 0 15 40.0148 556.9449 Tm
[<0003007000640059006E005F004300D0>-48<00030044004C>-47<000300CA006E>1<0066003D00ED>-48<000300BA007B0065005C003D>-48<000300700059006E005F005500D0>-47<0003007000650063009D004300D0>-48<0003007F006800FD00DA>-48<00030007000C000C000C0008>-45<0003006E006900CC>-47<000300EF007B00640052>-49<000300BA007B005F003D00ED>-48<000300EC007B004100ED>-48<00030101>-47<0003007B0065002200D0>]TJ
ET
EMC 
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC 
BT
/C2_0 1 Tf
15 0 0 15 40.0148 534.9449 Tm
[<0003008B0053007D003D>-289<0003007000650063009D0043006E003D>-289<000300D2007B00680062004300D0>-291<000300E50077>]TJ
ET
EMC
```

In contrast to the instructions on page 16, though, the **x** coordinates here are `40.0148` which clearly is inside the **CropBox** of page 17.

---

Beware: Above I said *the fifth entries of those text matrix setting instructions (**Tm**) essentially is the **x** coordinate from which the following text drawing instruction will draw text left-to-right.* The coordinates meant here are the ***current** user space coordinates*.

If there had been **cm** instructions before, the current user space coordinates would *not* necessarily be the ***default** user space coordinates* in which the crop box is defined.

In case of your document, though, no **cm** instruction is used before the instructions discused above.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
The first two options are not possible in my case, I'm forced to go with the last option.
But when talking about text objects do you mean Tj and TJ inside a BT?
Or do you mean content objects that contains the streams-BTs-?

cm, q, and Q used to order BTs inside a content objects, or to order content objects "pages"?
In my case the content objects that contains the streams are ordered in their right order(page 2 comes after page 1..) at least till now.
The ordering I’m concern with is the order within a content object, how to order BTs and also Tj/J inside them?

Comment: If I only consider Tm,Td,TD and T* with no further information is it possible to order them?

for the second question, No the content object is referenced by only one page, but that content contains BTs that belong to the page it referenced by and the following page.
so the following page is referencing another content object.

Comment: *"But when talking about text objects do you mean"* - A PDF *text object* according to the specification is started by a **BT** and terminated by an **ET**, see ISO 32000-1, section 9.4.1. *"In my case the content objects that contains the streams are ordered in their right order(page 2 comes after page 1..) at least till now"* - what do you mean by that? I hope you find the pages as specified, i.e. via the **Pages** tree, and from there access the page **Contents**, and don't blindly look for streams which may be content streams in the file, hoping they come in one-by-one page-by-page...

Comment: *"If I only consider Tm,Td,TD and T* with no further information is it possible to order them?"* - If you only consider them (and of course the advances by previous text showing instructions), you can merely order text chunks *within* text objects and have to make assumptions concerning the order of text objects as a whole. *"but that content contains BTs that belong to the page it referenced by and the following page."* - You mean there are text showing instructions drawing text you don't find on the associated page? Then that text is merely invisible on the page but it is there.

Comment: Please provide example PDFs to illustrate the issues you have - from your descriptions alone I merely get a very hazy impression of what there might be.

Comment: _"I hope you find the pages as specified, i.e. via the Pages tree, and from there access the page Contents"_
Yes I’m literally tracing a tree to go to the pages.
So what I understand is that I can order BT’s using cm q and Q
Then to order the TJ\j within a BT it can be done by using Tm,Td,TD and T* without involving cm?
_"Then that text is merely invisible on the page but it is there"_
No it is visible.

Comment: The pdf is not in English but [here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUrcX2aG07eT0tbSrrGwbkrdms01_XAo/view?usp=sharing) object number 127.

Here a [closer look at object 127](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WF7-7xjGKUm-BfTmJ7kBNu8Jij036OZYvTPonmNzW-A/edit?usp=sharing) and how it looks in [natural  pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qb5hhsWojcyUKobX5bBZG99E9POeOq56/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you simply share the PDF itself? Your "here it is" appears somehow preparsed, not a PDF anymore.

Comment: [Here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xX9SE9iEP7Z6Hm5s9lAulBlJDpD8jzx7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ok, I'm having a look at it. To start with, though: in contrast to what you appear to think the whole content stream (object # 128) of page 16 (object # 127) belongs to that page 16, including the parts you marked in blue and green in your "closer look at object 127". Can you explain why you think they don't?

Comment: Sorry I messed things up, It should be a closer look at obj 128,
But yes I decoded the entire stream in obj 128 and it showed text from the two pages(16 and 17),
but I think you’re right. obj 131 which is content stream of page 17 contains almost the same stream as in obj 128(the whole blue part in “closer look at obj 127”).
like  they are halfly duplicated, 
but how is that when you open the pdf, page 16 only shows it part ”the green one”?

Comment: *but how is that when you open the pdf, page 16 only shows it part ”the green one”?* - See the edit to my answer. In essence, almost all of the text in the blue section is drawn off-screen, outside the crop box of the page and outside the clip path active when drawing.